# How to get current page nearest parent id?

Tags: wp-query, menus, pages, meta-query

I am trying to get current page nearest parent id not top-level. For example I have added page like this:

[image]

Now If I am in `Junior Design Award 2013` page I want to get his parent id `765` not top-level parent id `691`

I have tried bellow code but I am getting top-level id which is `691`.

function.php

```
function get_root_parent_id( $page_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $parent = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT post_parent FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type='page' AND post_status='publish' AND ID = '$page_id'" );
    if( $parent == 0 ){
        return $page_id;
    }else{
        return get_root_parent_id( $parent );
    } 
}
```

page.php

```
global $post;     // if outside the loop
$page_object = get_queried_object();
$page_id  = get_queried_object_id(); // Get current page id

echo $root_parent_id = get_root_parent_id( $page_id );
```

Any Idea?

Thanks.

Comment: `$post->post_parent` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this.

```
global $post;     // if outside the loop
$page_object = get_queried_object();
$page_id  = get_queried_object_id(); // Get current page id

$args = array(
    'sort_order' => 'ASC',
    'sort_column' => 'post_title',
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'exclude' => '',
    'include' => $page_id,
    'meta_key' => '',
    'meta_value' => '',
    'authors' => '',
    'child_of' => 0,
    'parent' => -1,
    'exclude_tree' => '',
    'number' => '',
    'offset' => 0,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
); 
$pages = get_pages($args);

$parentID = $pages[0]->post_parent; // Get current page parent id
```

This will gives you current page parent id, not top-level id `$parentID = $pages[0]->post_parent;`

Comment: Excellent thumbs up to you :)